# How to remove all special characters from an NSMutableAttributedString (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have an NSMutableAttributed string `attributedString` in which I'm trying to remove all special characters "@". However, when I try to change the string value of attributedString, it gives the error that the string is a get only property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as the error says `string` property of a `NSMutableAttributedString` is readonly and you cannot set it. Instead you could use `mutableString` property of the attributed string and change it according to your need. Your code should look something similar to this:

```
attributedString.mutableString.replaceOccurrences(of: "@", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.mutableString.length));
```

And according to the documentation:

> The receiver tracks changes to this string and keeps its attribute
>   mappings up to date.

So you are not going to lose any styling information, as well!